# Click cell-card and redirect external URL

Tags: layout, bixby

In bixby, cell-card have attribute that 'on-click'. Before read doc I think it can be used to link on external URL but in doc say 'move to another component in bixby'.

Is anyone know about link to external URL? Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the [app-launch](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.app-launch) attribute of [result view](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view).

The app-launch attribute would allow your capsule to exit users from Bixby and open a client app. This attribute belongs to the result view layout which can be defined to match the output of a particular model within your capsule.